# MS word page numbering in file, continue after previous file

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers, document-automation

Good morning...
I wonder if automation in word has reached the level what i think ?
I have a folder that contains several chapters separately.
Now, Everytime when I change whatever/anything in my file, the page numbers changes.
Is there any way to automate the page number in my next chapter (that is in separate doc but placed in same folder/directory) automatically continue from the previous chapter.
**Means I want to automate doc2 page number continue after where the doc1 ends.**
We can read data in MS Exel from the separate xls file.
Can we do this in page numbering read from separate file??

Thanks for the response (in advance).
Cheers!!!

Rajesh Kumar Rai

Comment: Take a look at this article by Word MVP Jonathan West: http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=148.  You could use Word's Master Documents feature to gather your chapters for printing. In that case, the ordinary page number field should work. Do read the linked page first though. This feature is dangerous to your content if not used exactly correctly.

Comment: For making the page numbering continuous across multiple documents see the macro by Allen Wyatt at https://wordribbon.tips.net/T011572_Automatic_Page_Numbers_across_Multiple_Documents

Comment: The Macro Solution Discussion lists the Problems "gotchas" I listed in my Answer , thanks for the useful Article @CharlesKenyon , the other Article is 404 !

Comment: Here is the archival link to Jonathan West's article: https://web.archive.org/web/20130917135242/http:/pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not Possible by Word Settings, but Possible by Macro which will look into the Directory & Process it to generate a new Document.

Either way, you should not go that way, because it is going to break.

Imagine DOC1 has 10 Pages & you make DOC2 which (via Macro Automation) will start with Page 11 , because the Macro checked & got 10 Pages in last DOC1.

Now when you edit DOC1 to make it 8 Pages, what will occur in DOC2 ? Pages 9 & 10 will be missing.

More-over, what about making DOC1 have more Pages like 11 & 12. What will happen in DOC2 where Pages 11 & 12 will mess things.

What if you make the Automation to always check the Directory to generate the Page Numbers to avoid such Problems ?

Well , in that case, you can not move the Documents out the Directory to some other Directory. You can not even share with team mates over email.
More-over, you will have to check the Page Numbering all all Documents every time to make things synchronized , other-wise things will break.

Best Alternative I can think of :
Make a Master Document with all Chapters. Edit occurs only in Master Document. When-ever you want, you can use Automation to save the Individual Chapters with Page numbers, but these Chapter Documents will be read-only (eg to share with team members) , while All Editing will occur on Master Document.

Comment: If you can share the macro to do the same. It will be appreciated. Let me try the Macro. It seems a bit useful.

Comment: See https://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart. There should be no editing done to subdocuments when in the Master Document structure.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware that Master Document was a concept given by MS Word. I was using that term in a general sense. [[ I see that the Master Document functionality given by MS Word is "horrible" & We should not use that ! I was not talking about that in my Answer. ]] I was only saying that we should use Single Document for editing & save Multiple Documents Chapter-Wise for sharing. @CharlesKenyon

Comment: You can try to make the VBA Macro based on your Exact requirements ( which files to check , which files to update , when to update , which Sections to update , which Sections to ignore , etc ) but it will break easily & you will lose your Documents due to corruption, which I have high-lighted in the Answer itself. In case you still want to proceed , @RajeshKumarRai , you can use the Starting Point in these Articles ( & the other Articles in the Comment Chains ) :

Comment: : [[ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.pagenumbers.add ]] && [[ https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/macro-to-count-number-of-pages-per-word-file-in-folder.1005204/ ]] && [[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515203/add-page-number-in-word-using-vba ]] && [[ https://www.codevba.com/Word/PageNumbers/Add.htm ]]